# How to set up Eclipse TPTP

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, profiling

I need to profile a java application for a customer. It's an eclipse/maven project, so I decided on using eclipse TPTP ( http://www.eclipse.org/tptp ).

I tried to install eclipse TPTP through the update manager from a standard eclipse installation, but I gave up because of the unbelievable complex setup and downloading of dependencies with very cryptic names.

Then I downloaded the "all in one TPTP 4.5.1" package from http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/?ver=4.5.1 but when I start it up, it pops up an error saying "The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate it's companion shared library".

I'm running Windows XP, Sun Java 1.5, and clicked on "eclipse.exe" in the unpacked eclipse TPTP installation.

What do I need to do to get eclipse TPTP running?

Comment: I had some problems because my default java version on my machine. Try starting eclipse with a specific jvm in -vm parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use Netbeans to profile an Eclipse Application.

I have a blog post on the link below that explains how to configure both applications:

http://www.jroller.com/ortegon/entry/on_profiling_eclipse_rcp_applications

It works very well.  I've been profiling this way from over a year.  Easy to use, easy to setup and nice graphics also.

I found installing TPTP a pain, at least the version I used is not very well integrated with Eclipse.  It took me a very long time to get it to work correctly.  Netbeans was way quicker to learn and to get up to speed.  In the newer versions, it is also possible to import the source code of the Eclipse Projects using a special netbeans plugin (albeit it needs to be downloaded separately).

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for the great tip! I read your blogpost and had to fiddle a bit to get it working for my configuration. The problems were minor, and error messages were relatively clear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

[VisualVM 1.1.1](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) is a nice alternative to using NetBeans, being a standalone app, so you don't have to bring a Maven/Ant/Eclipse project into it's project format.  It can see any local Java process upon opening, so just double click your app in the list of Java processes and off you go.  You can:

1. Take Heap Dumps
2. Compare Memory Snapshots
3. [View garbage collection with the VisualGC plugin](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/plugins.html)
4. [Run BTrace scripts](https://btrace.dev.java.net/) to add run-time profiling & debugging advice to your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you update to Java 1.6u7 or better, you'll get access to the VisualVM tool that is essentially the same as the Netbeans Profiler.

I tried to use the Eclipse Test and Performance Tools package, but it just didn't work as well as the Netbeans profiler.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange. I've tried the all in one package and it works without a problem on Windows XP with Java 1.5 
Is it not possible that you use 64 bit version of Windows? Maybe that could be the cause of the problem.

I personaly don't use TPTP very much. I think NetBeans profiler gives more - at least more understandable - information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try downloading the "Java 1.5+ (JVMTI) Profiler SDK" (runtime) from
http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/?ver=4.5.1

I also think IBM's latest Rational Developer integrates this technology (there is 60 days trial). You can see how they configure it there.