# spring insight with org.codehaus.paranamer

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-insight

I have a java spring GWT web application. I need to use a profiler to view why is a certain function that slow (on server)... After some searching, seems that insight is a good way... tried it and it works... what I did is create a tc server instance (developer edition) with insight and add the project to it. It works.

The problem here is that I use maven plugin "org.codehaus.paranamer", that is a plugin that I use to get function paramater names... It works post-compilation to add a special private field in the class that holds the parameters names.

This is a problem with insight since it seems that it modifies the code too and that it works on the source code not the compiled version in the target folder.

What I can do to make this work? FYI, all I need is profile the app.. not necessarily with insight....

**Edit**:

I ended up using visualvm... It can help with profiling the app on the cpu level and the memory level...  That is the way I can use the common remote profiling mechanism jerry was talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For profile of JAVA apps(including tomcat instances), I strongly recommend the TPTP(Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform). You can read a lot here:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html

Especially for TPTP working with tomcat instance:

http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/02/10/tutorialprofiling-with-tptp-and-tomcat.html

Some of the information in the above article may be outdated, but main workflow is the same.

For commercial profilers, I will recommend yourkit profiler: http://www.yourkit.com/

I don't know if there is a trial edition available now, but years ago, this profile is more user friendly than TPTP.

Comment: I initially tried TPTP but it doesn't install on STS (springsource toolsuite)... and they are deprecating the project... not sure why.

Comment: @AhHatem, yes, install TPTP within eclipse is miserable for the last time I tried it. You can check the similar question here, they are recommending Netbeans. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186615/how-to-set-up-eclipse-tptp

Comment: Also, for profiling tomcat instance, I think TPTP, Yourkit, Netbeans all use the same "remote" profiling mechanism, that is, the profiler will attach to a socket opened by the instructed JVM. So I don't think you need extra effort to import your project to Netbeans.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand how do I use that common mechanism if I can't seem to be able to install TPTP...